# How to save multiple radio button value to sqlite in ios?

Tags: sqlite

In My Application,I inserted Five Radio Buttons in Single View Controller.I want to get each button value whenever We select the radio button.After that,We store the button value to Sqlite.

Comment: And what is the actual problem with your code?

Comment: i have no know idea about that.I want some idea otherwise send me the sample code link related to my queries

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking to store values in a SQLite table, then you had best start by implementing some form of data store.  Apple provides something called CoreData, it's not my favourite piece of software especially for noobs but there is lots of help and examples out there.

Failing that, you could always pick a SQLite wrapper or ORM implementation that is easier to use.

As your initial requirement is fairly simple, I would probably browse around to try and find something that is quick and easy to implement.

Obviously I have my favourite (http://db-access.org/) and i'm hugely biased, but there are loads out there to choose from.

A popular choice is one called FMDB.